# npm ERR! command sh -c -- node ./bin/postInstall while creating react native expo app using ignite on Mac

Tags: react-native

Facing below error while creating react native using ignite,

I am using below command to generate react native App

```
npx ignite-cli@latest new PizzaApp
```

I am getting below issue after running the above command

```
No patch files found
./bin/postInstall failed on command:
  if [ -d "ios" ]; then cd ios && pod install && cd -; fi
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Volumes/Technology/projects/react-native/HealthTracker
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node ./bin/postInstall

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myname/.npm/_logs/2022-11-15T19_13_21_699Z-debug-0.log
```

I am using,

OS - macOS Ventura

node - v18.12.1

npm - 8.19.2

ruby - ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [x86_64-darwin22]

I have tried below things

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved after update, upgrading brew and restarting machine.

```
brew update

brew upgrade
```